# Encoding arabic letters from JsonArray doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble encoding Arabic letters, sometimes it works probably and shows up Arabic letters other times it just ends up showing "??????" is there a way to fix it?

```
response = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(response, "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
JSONObject jObjSource = new JSONObject(response);
String contnet = Html.fromHtml(jObjSource.getString("content")).toString();
System.out.println(contnet);
mContentText.setText(contnet);
database.updateNewsRow(ID, contnet);
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I don't think `UTF-8` supports Arabic. How about `UTF-16` or `UTF-32`?

Comment: @Neiwiert are you sure? i thought utf-8 supports the same set of characters as utf-16? (which would be the unicode characterset)

Comment: Hold on I will give it a try, but if UTF-8 doesn't support Arabic why would it work at some point?

Comment: @ParkerHalo No I'm not 100% sure but I don't think the entire arabic 'alphabet' fits in 1 byte.

Comment: @busted13 because it will try to parse it as best as it can and some can be parsed and some cant.

Comment: @Neijwiert you're right, but utf-8 is not necessarily 1 byte long... the genius thing using utf-8 is that 1 character can be up to (i think) 6 bytes long. [UTF-8 Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: @ParkerHalo huh? Would be some weird naming going on then if it wasn't 1 byte. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): "The encoding is variable-length and uses 8-bit code units". WAIT I'm stupid you are right haha oops.

Comment: @Neijwiert the € sign in utf-8 is encoded as `0xE2 0x82 0xAC` in 3 bytes! But i think this is a bit offtopic here, but we can discuss in chat if you want to :)! Those "code units" just say that every utf-8 character is divisible by 8!